# Dropdown option in grid inline edit is empty

Tags: magento2, grid, customizable-options, inline-editor

I'm using magento v2.2.5 and i created a column with inline edit like this:

**xml ui component**

```
 <column name="enabled">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Enabled</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Module\Model\Source\EnabledOptions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

**Namespace\Module\Model\Source\EnabledOptions**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Source;

class EnabledOptions implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public static function getOptionArray()
    {
        $options['yes'] = __("Yes");
        $options['no'] = __("No");
        return $options;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }

        return $result;
    }


    public function getOptionText($optionId)
    {
        $options = self::getOptionArray();

        return isset($options[$optionId]) ? $options[$optionId] : null;
    }
}
```

but i got an empty options like this:

[image]

**edit:**

after i inspected the browser console, there is an error like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code

```
<column name="enabled">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Module\Model\Source\EnabledOptions</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enabled</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: is that code working @Shell Suite ?

Comment: not working, it makes my table column record empty too

Comment: @AnsarHusain have you found a solution? I am having this issue too

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for this please bellow what works for me all I was missing was `template`:

```
<column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Active</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```